# Hotspot Analysis Output Color Disappears When I Reload the File in Another Project

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hot-spot

I am using ArcGIS desktop 10.x. I used hot spot analysis on a couple of points feature classes, and saved the output to a gdb in shapefile format.

I then reload the shapefiles in a newly created project, but the coloration of hot/cold spot no longer exists.

Should I export the output into another format in order to reload, or other kinds of gdb? Or is it that I can not reload the analysis output in another project whatsoever?

Comment: By "the coloration of hot/cold spot no longer exists," do you mean that its just a black and white image? Or is the file containing the hotspot not loading?

Comment: You can right click on the layer, go to properties, symbology, and adjust the color ramp there. And note for the future: Shapefiles do not save symbology (or coloration). Layer files do, however. Just change the type of export to a layer file.

Answer (score 2):

You want to go into properties, then symbology and use a color ramp for either the GiZScore or the GiPValue, depending on what it is you want to show.  This is how the hotspot result maps originally.